# how to get the items of a single order in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm still beginner in laravel. I have three models: Item, Item_Order, Order.
I want to get the items for each product in show function.

**tables**

```
------  --------      -----------
items    item_order     order
------- --------      --------
id        order_id       id
name      item_id        name
```

**Order Controller**

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
        $items = Item::with('item_order')->where('id',items)->get();

        return view('vendor.multiauth.admin.orders.show',compact('order','items'));
    }
```

**In Item model**

```
   public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
    }
```

**In Order Model**

```
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item','item__order','item_id');
    }
```

Comment: You need the order for each item right?

Comment: `item__order` the underscore here looks kind of wide

Comment: items for each product? couldn't understand the actual question and what were you trying to do? if you want all the items of the order $order->items() would do the job.

Answer (score -2):

If you want it to show like this on 1 page like this:

```
items    item_order     order
------- --------      --------
id        order_id       id
name      item_id        name
```

You can do something like this in your controller:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $account = AccountModel::find($id);
        if (!is_null($account)) {
            $items = Item::paginate(10);
            $order = Order::paginate(10);
            $item_order= Item_Order::paginate(10);
            return view('vendor.multiauth.admin.orders.show', [
                'account' => $account,
                'items' => $items,
                'order' => $order,
                'item_order' => $item_order,
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

And then in your model do:

```
return $this->hasOne(ModelOfThePageYouShow::class, 'account_id');
```

And in your view:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>item</th>
            <th>account_id</th>
        </tr>
            @foreach ($items as $item)
            <tr>
                <th>{{ $item->id }}</th>
                <th>{{ $item->name}}</th>
                <th>{{ $item->account_id }}</th>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @foreach ($item_order as $item_order)
            <tr>
                <th>{{ $item_order->id }}</th>
                <th>{{ $item_order->name}}</th>
                <th>{{ $item_order->account_id }}</th>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
            @foreach ($order as $order)
            <tr>
                <th>{{ $order->id }}</th>
                <th>{{ $order->item}}</th>
                <th>{{ $order->account_id }}</th>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
</table>
```

Of course you have to change the value's to the things you have, but with this i hope you can figure it out.

I probably made some mistakes somewhere, if someone want to correct me, please do so.